# How to disable other payment method when using gift card for purchasing a product in shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How to make sure that if a customer is purchasing products using gift card then he won't be able to use any other method to pay. he can pay by either any payment method or by using gift card but not both.

example - if a customer have a $500 worth gift card and its cart value is $1000 dollar then he won't be able to pay using gift card.

i have tried using shopify script, but won't able to know if the cart is using gift card or not.

Comment: Why do you care? A gift card is cash in your shop. It's only purpose is for exactly your use case. If I have a $500 card and a $1000 checkout, and you tell me I cannot use my gift card, then your store is broken and will piss me off. Why do that?

Comment: i dont know my client want that, please share if you have any idea

Comment: @Atul have you got any work around. We need same functionality.

Comment: @RohitGoel no still stuck at this point